# Not sure if naming convention in abstract generic class is valid

Tags: java, interface, java-8, abstract-class, dto

Got a question, I couldn't find valid names for this variables `S itemState` and `D itemDTO` cause these names are confusing if you get object what you really want (eg. `S extends ItemState` and you really get `S` type, not `ItemState`)

```
public abstract class ItemData<S extends ItemState, D extends ItemDTO>
                                 implements ItemDataInterface<S> {
    private S itemState;
    private D itemDTO;
    //code
}
```

Should I use `ex` prefix or `specified` (which is too long IMO)?

Comment: Maybe rename the class `ItemState` to `BaseItemState` instead?

Comment: Why not use State extends ItemState and DTO extends ItemDTO

Comment: The confusion stems from the attempt to name the variable after its *type* instead of its *role*. If the role is so generic that its type is already describing it, `itemState` is fine. In Java, every reference type variable may point to an instance of a subclass, that’s something you don’t have to emphasize every time. Consider AWT: `Container.add(Component component)`; of course, `component` can be a subclass of `Component` and in fact, it always is, as `Component` is `abstract`. But that’s no reason to emphasize that trivial fact in the parameter variable name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to @J_mie6 comment, I used:

```
private S state;
private D dto;
```

It assumed to be the best option.